# Even when user has 'bulkadmin' role, query says user does not have role - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I am facing a weird issue with SQL Server 2012.

I have a user (say `RS\sqluser`) which has `bulkadmin` role.

Now when i run this query

`Select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('bulkadmin', 'RS\sqluser')`

output is **0**. But when i execute this query

`sp_helpsrvrolemember 'bulkadmin'`

I can see `RS\sqluser` present in the list.

Can someone please help me understand how is the output differing or is it BUG in SQL Server 2012? (Can't be a BUG as same query with different user works fine)

Comment: Did you try removing the login from the role, and then re-adding?

Answer (score 2):

You could have problems whereby the DC is not available, the user is actually a Windows group, or you could possibly have UAC issues. It may even be a permissions issue in AD as regards the account (run xp_logininfo 'RS\sqluser' and see if you get an 0x5 error).

I prefer to directly query the system tables to get that sort of information:

```
SELECT  1
FROM    sys.server_principals sp
        INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members srm ON sp.principal_id = srm.member_principal_id
        INNER JOIN sys.server_principals sp2 ON srm.role_principal_id = sp2.principal_id
WHERE   sp2.name = 'bulkadmin'
        AND sp.name = 'RS\sqluser';
```